# CppRest GET not receiving body?

Tags: postman, wikipedia, cpprest-sdk

I'm trying to GET the content of the revision history of a Wikipedia page to parse the various revisions' date and size.

When I'm running a GET on `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Barbecue&action=history` with Postman (after having disabled the additional elements added by Postman's settings) I'm getting the full page with the all the body's content.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with CPPRESTSDK with the following code

```
#include "cpprest/http_client.h"

using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;

void main()
{
  http_client mHttpClient(U("https://en.wikipedia.org"));

  http_request mRequest(methods::GET);
  mRequest.set_request_uri(U("w/index.php?title=Barbecue&action=history"));
  mRequest.headers().add(header_names::content_type, U("text/html"));

  http_response wResponse;
  wResponse = mHttpClient.request(mRequest).get();
  ucout << wResponse.to_string();
}
```

which I would expect to yield the same thing that Postman gives me, but it looks like I'm only getting the header of the response. What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to do it.

At first I tried to `wait()` on the `http_response` but the execution was jamming there. When I decided to read the response `char` by `char`, I saw that not only I was receiving a full response, but that this response was never ending and priting `-1` until Ragnarok.

My hypothesis was that the Wiki servers keep the connection alive in case they want to broadcast an event to the browser and in fact, looking at the source of the page you can find this bit of code:

```
var messaging = vAPI.messaging;
...
messaging.Connection.pagehide = function() {
   for ( var connection of this.connections.values() ) {
        connection.disconnect();
        connection.handler(connection.toDetails('connectionBroken'));
    }
}.bind(messaging);
window.addEventListener('pagehide', messaging.Connection.pagehide);
```

which totally looks like something that would keep a GET request connection opened :)

---

Here's the code I used to get the page's html in the end. I just read it bit by bit until I get a `-1`, so far it does the trick. If you playing with that, keep these servers' rate limiting in mind. Happy scraping!

```
#include "cpprest/http_client.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace utility;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;

void main()
{
  http_client wHttpClient(U("https://en.wikipedia.org"));

  http_request wRequest(methods::GET);
  wRequest.set_request_uri(U("w/index.php?title=Barbecue&action=history"));

  http_response wResponse = wHttpClient.request(wRequest).get();

  long l;
  string str;

  while (true)
  {
    l = wResponse.body().read().get();
    if (l == -1) { break; }
    str += static_cast<char>(l);
  }

  cout << str;
}
```